# SQLite date extraction technique

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to select a date which is stored in the form of YYYYMMDD as INT type in the database. Now, here I have a scenario where the user enters the date of his choice and i want to extract only the date that is lower or equal to the value entered by the user.

I started with the following sql statement:

```
"SELECT date FROM transactionRegister WHERE date<='"+dateInput+"'";
```

But this would load up all the results which are satisfied by the statement which will just make my app inefficient.

I only want the first result to be loaded up in the cursor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want 1 result, tell the DB that via `LIMIT 1`. That guarantees one result (may not be the correct result).

To fix that, tell the DB how to order the results, for "closest first" `ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply just use "Limit" end of your sql statement. your sql statement must be like this:

```
"SELECT date FROM transactionRegister WHERE date<='"+dateInput+"' ORDER BY date DESC Limit 1";
```

Limit shows only the number that you specified for. for example Limit 20 return only 20 rows of your statement.